# Is there a more "active record" proper way of writing this query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following works, properly, but seems like I'm probably not utilizing something in rails that I should be. The working bit is:

```
MaxOffer.joins("JOIN items ON items.id = max_offers.item_id")
        .order('amount_in_cents desc')
        .where('items.id = 20')
        .limit(5).collect do |moffer|
```

At first I assumed I didn't have to explicitly use a join since the models are:

```
class MaxOffer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
  has_many :max_offers
```

But got errors when I tried to simply use `item.id` in the where clause. Is there a more proper way to do this, or is explicitly including the join necessary?

Comment: In general, I think though that what you've done is pretty good. The changes I proposed are pretty minor really.

Comment: the only reason I wasn't using a placeholder int he where was because I'm just trying to get the hang of activerecord -- but its nice to have gotten some confirmation that I wasn't missing out on some rails magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the relationships between MaxOffer and Item, this should work:

```
MaxOffer.joins(:item)
    .where('items.id = ?', 20)
    .order('amount_in_cents desc')
    .limit(5).collect do |moffer|
```

I'd run them both and look at the sql generated to see if there are differences.

Comment: apparently it has to be `.joins(:item)` (singular) ... I had actually tried your example before you posted it based on the docs on [the RoR website](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) -- but the guide is apparently incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for the note -- I corrected my answer.  It may depend on which direction you're specifying. e.g. `MaxOffer.joins(:item)` -v- `User.joins(:max_offers)` depending on if the relationship is `belongs_to` or `has_many`.